# ExtJs: basic questions

Tags: extjs

I'm currently learning ExtJs, but I can't seem to grasp my mind arround the following.
What is the difference between the array notation and the requires notation

For example:

```
view['MyPanel']
model['MyModel']
controller['MyController']
store['MyStore']

requires: ['namespace.view.MyPanel']
```

Do they do the same or ... ?
And why do I have to put **ALL** the views, models, controllers and stores used in the application inmediatley in the app.js?

Can someone clear those thing out to me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requires will just load the files matching the class name from the server. It will not instantiate anything. You should require what is needed in each view/controller/model, you don't need to have it all in app.js.

For instance, if you have a MyModel that has a relation to MySubModel, then MyModel would require MySubModel. Requires is essentially about loading other classes when needed so that they are fetched from the server before being used - since using a class when it is not loaded creates a noticable delay due to ExtJS having to fetch the class from the server before instantiating it.

The models, views and controllers arrays in a controller are a convinient way to require such resources as you don't have to specify the path to the models/controllers/views folders. See the docs on [controller models config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-models) for example.

A guide on [how to structure your application is available here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/application_architecture) even though I don't really like that they load all views and all controllers in this approach. But it's a good start. You can dynamically load stuff later on when your application grows.